# play audio with javascript function from a php for loop

Tags: javascript, php, audio

Hi i have a list of songs and am fetching them with php, i want to pass this audio to a javascript function. am presently using this function to play but it does not pause a previous audio when i click on another audio in the loop and also my play class does not change to pause when i click on the play button

```
function play(src){    
var myaudio = new Audio(src);
var isPlaying = false;
myaudio.loop = true;
function play(){

if (isPlaying) {
myaudio.pause()

var target = document.getElementById("pl");
target.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
target.classList.toggle("fa-play");

} else {
myaudio.play();
 var target = document.getElementById("pl");
target.classList.toggle("fa-play");
target.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
}

};

myaudio.onplaying = function() {
 isPlaying = true;
};
myaudio.onpause = function() {
 isPlaying = false;
 }; 
 };
```

this is my html and php

```
  <?php

                        $count = 1;
                       $noarry = DataDB::getInstance()->get_rows_from_field('music','group_id',$value);
                        foreach($noarry as $row):?>
            <ul id="insert_songMenu">    
                <li>
                    <div class="sort_num"><?php echo $count++;?>.</div>
                    <div class="song_name">
                        <i class="noItalics"><?php echo $row['music_name'];?></i>
                        <span><?php echo $row['by'];?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content_feature">
                    <cite class="fa fa-play" onclick=play("user/<?php echo $usern.'/'.$row['snippet']; ?>")></cite>

                    </div>
                </li>

                 <?php endforeach; ?>`
```

Comment: What should *src* be?

Comment: src is the directory of the audio to be played which is fetched from onclick @Jonasw

Comment: do hv to do it like this, can't u use an audio player ?

Comment: this cause i customized my play interface

Comment: ok let me see wat i cn do den, its nt gona be preety.

Comment: thanks @RiazLaskar

Comment: @nsikak it should work if everything goes well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place somewhere above php

i think this should work fine.
JS :

```
var song_list = {};
function play(src,self) {
  for(song in song_list)
  {
         song_list[song].file.pause();
   }
    var myaudio = song_list[src].file;
    var isPlaying = song_list[src].isPlaying;
    myaudio.loop = true;



        if (isPlaying) {
            myaudio.pause()

            var target = self;
            target.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
            target.classList.toggle("fa-play");

        } else {
            myaudio.play();
            var target = self;
            target.classList.toggle("fa-play");
            target.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
        }



    myaudio.onplaying = function() {
        song_list[src].isPlaying = true;
    };
    myaudio.onpause = function() {
        song_list[src].isPlaying = false;
    };
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$count  = 1;
$noarry = DataDB::getInstance()->get_rows_from_field('music', 'group_id', $value);
foreach ($noarry as $row):
?>
           <ul id="insert_songMenu">    
                <li>
                    <div class="sort_num"><?php echo $count++; ?>.</div>
                    <div class="song_name">
                        <i class="noItalics"><?php echo $row['music_name']; ?></i>
                        <span><?php echo $row['by']; ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="content_feature">
                    <cite class="fa fa-play" onclick=play("user/<?php echo $usern . '/' . $row['snippet']; ?>",this)></cite>

                    </div>
                </li>
           <script>
             song_list["user/<?php echo $usern . '/' . $row['snippet']; ?>"] = { 
                        file : new Audio("user/<?php echo $usern . '/' . $row['snippet']; ?>"), 
                        isPlaying : false
                        };
           </script>
                 <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

try this

Comment: am still having the same problem

Comment: it still plays the old song alongside the newly selected one. so there is  a clash kind of thing

Comment: ok, so u want to play only one song at a time ?? a quick qstn
can u pause and play songs  ?

Comment: if i click on play on a the second song while the first is playing, it doesnt stop the first instead it plays both together

Comment: remove this line ` if(song_list[song].isPlaying)` and test again.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply stop the previous:

```
var myaudio=null;
function play(src){  
   if(myaudio) myaudio.pause();  
   myaudio = new Audio(src);
   ...
}
```